# Mat-Menu not applying style when using custom theme

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a custom material theme but when I use mat-menu it seems that it is not applying the theme as can be seen in the image below:

[image]

The code for the custom theme is as follows:

```
.light {
  $light-primary: mat-palette($md-primary-blue, 500);
  $light-accent:  mat-palette($md-primary-blue, 900);
  $light-warn:    mat-palette($mat-red, 600);
  $light-theme: mat-light-theme($light-primary, $light-accent, $light-warn);

  @include theme-color-grabber($light-theme);
  @include angular-material-theme($light-theme);

  @include mat-core-theme($light-theme);
  @include mat-checkbox-theme($light-theme);
  @include mat-card-theme($light-theme);
  @include mat-radio-theme($light-theme);
  @include mat-form-field-theme($light-theme); // Form-Field theme
  @include mat-input-theme($light-theme);      // Input Theme
  @include mat-menu-theme($light-theme);

}
```

And the code to display the mat-menu is as follows:

```
 <button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu">Menu</button>

  <mat-menu class="test" #menu="matMenu">
    <button mat-menu-item>Item 1</button>
    <button mat-menu-item>Item 2</button>
  </mat-menu>
```

When I use the built-in themes it seems to be working but with my custom theme it is not. Do I need to add an another item in the theme ?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who has this problem what i was missing is the following code which I added in the constructor of the AppComponent

```
@HostBinding('class') componentCssClass;

constructor(public overlayContainer: OverlayContainer){
  this.overlayContainer.getContainerElement().classList.add('light');
  this.componentCssClass = 'light';
}
```

Which produced the following result

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Though this question has already been answered I think this is worth putting up here.

I had a similar issue with the `MatMenu` component not respecting my theme rules for dark and light mode. The theme applies to the menu items but would not apply to custom `div` elements in the menu. @owen's solution is correct and I would like to add that;

If you have extra `div` elements in the menu with content, I solved the issue by wrapping the content of the menu into its own component and extending `MatCard` on the component class.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-menu',
  templateUrl: './menu.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./menu.component.scss'],
})
export class MenuComponent extends MatCard {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }
}
```

The `MatCard` component takes care of theming your text and icons in case they are not part of the conventional menu content.